# Device/interface orientation issue when app is entering foreground state

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6, uiinterfaceorientation, uideviceorientation

I have `UIViewController` instances managed by the `UINavigationViewController`. These VCs have to be only in portrait mode, but `ModalViewControllers` attached to the `UIViewControllers` must be in portrait and landscape mode.

So I did this in my project build file:

[image]

Then I sub-classed `UINavigationViewController` with this:

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}
```

Everything works great, best ever. Exactly what I want.

But let's imagine I am on the one of the `UIViewControllers` managed by the `UINavigationViewController` and the app goes into background and I do something else. And now I am in landscape mode (VERY IMPORTANT!) and I bring the app into foreground (normally, by taping the icon).

Everything is still ok, exactly what I want. VC is presented in portrait mode but if I want to volume up or down, this happens:

[image]

Of course, if I deselect landscape mode from the deploy info, the issue won't arise, but then I lose the ability for my Modals to be landscape.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I have the same issue... did you fix it? thanks

Comment: @silvaric nope. sorry for the delay. if you come up with the solution or workaround of any kind, please let me know. thanks.